# SQL Server: how to use manually defined column name for case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, case

I am using the following Select as part of a bigger query.

Can someone here tell me how I can refer to the manually defined name "`amountUSD`" in my Case statement ?
I am always getting the following error when trying to save it this way: 
"`Invalid column name 'amountUSD'.`"

A work-around would probably be to insert it into a temp table first but I was hoping I could avoid that.

```
SELECT      (CASE WHEN R.currency = 'USD' THEN '1' ELSE E.exchange_rate END) AS exchangeRate,
            (R.amount * E.exchange_rate) AS amountUSD,
            (
                CASE    WHEN amountUSD < 1000 THEN '18' 
                        WHEN amountUSD < 5000 THEN '25' 
                        WHEN amountUSD < 20000 THEN '27' 
                        WHEN amountUSD < 100000 THEN '28' 
                        WHEN amountUSD < 250000 THEN '29' 
                        WHEN amountUSD < 2000000 THEN '30' 
                        WHEN amountUSD < 5000000 THEN '31' END
            ) AS approvalLevel
FROM        Exchange_Rates E
WHERE       E.from_currency = R.currency
AND         E.to_currency = 'USD'
FOR XML     PATH(''), ELEMENTS, TYPE
```

Many thanks for any help with this, Tim.

Comment: Basically, unless you rewrite the conversion as a common table expression or subquery, you need to reference it as the full expression using only table fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will this work?

```
SELECT      (CASE WHEN R.currency = 'USD' THEN '1' ELSE E.exchange_rate END) AS exchangeRate,
            (R.amount * E.exchange_rate) AS amountUSD,
            (
                CASE    WHEN (R.amount * E.exchange_rate) < 1000 THEN '18' 
                        WHEN (R.amount * E.exchange_rate) < 5000 THEN '25' 
                        WHEN (R.amount * E.exchange_rate) < 20000 THEN '27' 
                        WHEN (R.amount * E.exchange_rate) < 100000 THEN '28' 
                        WHEN (R.amount * E.exchange_rate) < 250000 THEN '29' 
                        WHEN (R.amount * E.exchange_rate) < 2000000 THEN '30' 
                        WHEN (R.amount * E.exchange_rate) < 5000000 THEN '31' END
            ) AS approvalLevel
FROM        Exchange_Rates E
WHERE       E.from_currency = R.currency
AND         E.to_currency = 'USD'
FOR XML     PATH(''), ELEMENTS, TYPE
```

Comment: Thanks ! This works. I was thinking of this as well just thought there might be a better way but I don't see a big performance impact here so it should do the job.

Answer (score 2):

You can not - because amountUSD does not exist at this point. It only exists in the output projection. You have 2 choices:

- Not use amountUSD or
- Not use your table, but make a 2 step query, first project amountUSD, THEN select over that and make the case there (approvalLevel).

This is not as hard as it sounds as you can make a select over another select.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why amountUSD is not available in the SELECT list, is because of the Logical Order of Query Processing: http://tsql.solidq.com/books/insidetsql2008/Logical%20Query%20Processing%20Poster.pdf

I believe the below code is one of the possible solutions that will work as described by TomTom.

```
SELECT  *
        ,(CASE    WHEN amountUSD < 1000 THEN '18' 
                    WHEN amountUSD < 5000 THEN '25' 
                    WHEN amountUSD < 20000 THEN '27' 
                    WHEN amountUSD < 100000 THEN '28' 
                    WHEN amountUSD < 250000 THEN '29' 
                    WHEN amountUSD < 2000000 THEN '30' 
                    WHEN amountUSD < 5000000 THEN '31' END
        ) AS approvalLevel
FROM 
(
    SELECT      (CASE WHEN R.currency = 'USD' THEN '1' ELSE E.exchange_rate END) AS exchangeRate,
                (R.amount * E.exchange_rate) AS amountUSD,
    FROM        Exchange_Rates E
    WHERE       E.from_currency = R.currency
    AND         E.to_currency = 'USD'
) t
FOR XML     PATH(''), ELEMENTS, TYPE
```